# Awk programming integer format as 01 instead of 1

Tags: linux, awk

To change the output from `2012 1 5` to `20120105`, is it sufficient to change from

```
ls $run |xargs sed q |awk '{print $1,$2,$3} ' >> stin-2
```

to

```
ls $run |xargs sed q |awk '{printf "%2.2i" $1,$2,$3} ' >> stin-2
```

Comment: Why not just use `stat(1)` in the first place?

Comment: You can use `ls $run |xargs sed q |awk '{print $1," ",$2," ",$3} ' >> stin-2`.  Or `ls $run |xargs sed q |awk '{printf "%d %d %d", $1,$2,$3} ' >> stin-2`.  Heck, as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested, you can even use "stat" ;)

Comment: Don't parse the output from `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `printf()` (which is probably the correct to get the output you want) you should use as many conversion specifiers as there are arguments, like you would in C.

```
awk '{printf "%.4d%.2d%.2d\n", $1, $2, $3}'
```

Note the comma after the format; that is crucial.   The example code omits that, so it concatenates the given format string and `$1` as the format string, which is then given two arguments.  You probably want the newline too, which `printf()` does not add automatically (unlike `print`).  The choice of `%d` over `%i` is arbitrary; they're the same.  The use of `%.2d` is not entirely arbitrary; it achieves the same effect as `%2.2d`, but uses fewer characters to do the job.

This answer does not attempt to address whether what you're trying to do is sensible on the larger scale; it simply shows how it could/should be done assuming that it needs to be done.  There's also an assumption that there is a space between the fields for `2012 11 25`.